# Filter multiple columns by one condition Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple fields in Postgresql table of the same type which is bigint. I would like to select values which are in the int range (-2147483647, 2147483647). I tried to do something like this but with multiple fields it does not really look good:

```
select * from test_table
where field1 between -2147483647 and 2147483647  
  and field2 between -2147483647 and 2147483647  
  and field3 between -2147483647 and 2147483647
```

How can I apply one range filtering for multiple columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`int8range`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) combined with [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) and an array of the field values:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE int8range(-2147483647, 2147483647) @> ANY(ARRAY[field1, field2, field3])
```